# Notice of burnination: limitations

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Nominating [limitations](/questions/tagged/limitations) for burnination.  Totally meta, bro.

Please provide arguments against if you have any.

Comment: My arguments against burninating limitations are limited.

Comment: I think our ability to burninate this might be limited.

Comment: Without [limitations] how can we be sure the site won't become an [anythinggoes]?

Comment: It looks like the use-cases for this tag are...\*puts.sunglasses.on\*...limited. *YYEEEEAAAAAAHHHHHHHH*

Comment: I came here hoping to make a joke about limitations, only to find that there are no limitations on the number of jokes already made in this vein...

Comment: it seems the poor jokes are definitely limited... Seems likely this tag will mostly be used by people thinking it might be their issue, but if someone is asking a question for help it's mostly unlikely they will be aware beforehand that their inability to do something is due to limitations in a language/library/etc. As the amount of times this tag will be accurately used for something relevant is likely to be very low, and as other tags encapsulate the topic enough to leave "limitations" usage within the subject/question, imo, to avoid a potential gargantuan mass misuse, bin it.

Comment: @James: That's a nice answer.  Too bad I can't accept it.  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I tend to stay away from the answer box on meta. There's a lot of politics, and (mainly) a great deal of underlying knowledge and all things Stack/Meta to learn and understand in order to answer, usually. So it was just a comment. but thanks

Answer (score 5):

Why, yes, that would be a great idea.

Oh, wait, it's already gone.

Somebody mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)